# How to pre-populate (Multiple)ChoiceField in Django based on previous user selection

Tags: django, django-forms, django-queryset

I managed to store and update a selection of categories made by the user to the database. Now I want to pre-populate the MultipleChoiceSelect with this selection once the user queries the form again.

So my current form will always return all available categories. How can I apply the users personal selection to this to have his last selection pre-selected in the DOM?

```
# Models

class UserCategoryFilter(models.Model):
    """
    Saves the selected category filter by a user
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories_selected = models.CharField(max_length=2000)


class Category(models.Model):
    """
    Model to store all available categories
    """
    poller_category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

```
# Form

class SelectCategoryForm(forms.Form):
    choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(),
                                             widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

```
# View

@require_POST
def save_category_filter(request):

    [..]

        # Get the form instance
        filter_form = SelectCategoryForm(request.POST)

        # Form validation
        if filter_form.is_valid():


            # Get the cleaned data
            selection = filter_form.clean()

            # Check if user already has a filter instance
            instance_exists = UserCategoryFilter.objects.filter(user=request.user)

            # If not create, else update
            if not instance_exists:
                filter_instance = UserCategoryFilter(user=request.user,
                                                     categories_selected=selection)
                filter_instance.save()
            else:
                # Update existing instance
                UserCategoryFilter.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(categories_selected=selection)
                pass
        [..]
```

This is how the selection of the user is currently saved in `categories_selected`:

`{'choices': <QuerySet [<Category: Sports>, <Category: Lifestyle>]>}`

Comment: Can you share the `GET` view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is how the selection of the user is currently saved in `categories_selected`:
>
> `{'choices': <QuerySet [<Category: Sports>, <Category: Lifestyle>]>}`

That's not a friendly data structure. Instead, let's do `["Sports", "Lifestyle"]`.

```py
# Get the cleaned data
selection = filter_form.clean()
selection = json.dumps([c.poller_category for c in selection['choices']])  # Add this
```

Now, we can `json.loads` the selection and `.filter(poller_category__in=selection)`.

Then, we pass the initial choices in `SelectCategoryForm(initial={'choices': choices})`.

```py
@require_GET
def select_category(request):
    choices = ()
    user_category_filter_queryset = UserCategoryFilter.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    selection = user_category_filter_queryset.values_list('categories_selected', flat=True).first()
    if selection:
        try:
            selection = json.loads(selection)
        except JSONDecodeError:
            pass
        if selection:
            choices = Category.objects.filter(poller_category__in=selection)
    form = SelectCategoryForm(initial={
        'choices': choices,
    })
    return render(request, 'select-category.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the initial value of the choices field from when creating the form:

```
filter_form = SelectCategoryForm(
    request.POST, 
    initial={'choices': Category.objects.filter(<get_user's_category_here>)}
)
```

You didn't share the models so it's a bit tricky to build the query, but just change the filter to get the user's current categories.